# I want to print a certain dictionary key using the Counter class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a code that returns 'True' if the value is equal to the one before it and 'False' if it is not equal. I am now trying to use the Counter class to print out the sum of the values that returned False. However, I keep getting all dictionaries/keys returned instead of just the values associated with 'False'.

My code:

```
df['cols2'] = df['cols1'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) != len(x),raw= True).replace({0 : False, 1: True})


p = (df['cols2'] , Counter['False']) 

print (p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this :

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# Assuming you have already defined df and calculated 'cols2' using your previous code

# Create a Counter object from 'cols2'
counter_obj = Counter(df['cols2'])

# Access the count of occurrences of 'False' in the Counter object
false_count = counter_obj[False]

# Print the count
print("Count of 'False' in cols2:", false_count)
```